# How to install OpenCV 2.4.7 for Python , Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, installation

I am going to use a code shared on GitHub on facial feature extraction. This code has OpenCV 2.4.7 and Python 2.7 dependencies. I tried OpenCV 3.4, but it didn't work. This code uses cv2.Boost() which is not found in OpenCV 3.4. 
Also, pypi only support OpenCV 3x. I couldn't install OpenCV 2.4.7 by pip install.

Please let me know how I can install OpenCV 2.4.7 for Python? I prefer to install it in a Conda virtual environment.

O.S: Ubuntu 16;
I can use Windows 10 too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could build the OpenCV from source, so you can choose the branch (version) you want to use:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev

sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev

cd ~ 
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 2.4
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
make -j7
sudo make install
```

Good luck!

Comment: However, I suggest using the latest version of OpenCV if possible, which is surely more powerful.

Comment: Thanks. How can I import the built OpenCV in Spyder or PyCharm running in a conda virtual environment?

Comment: It should compile the OpenCV library with its support extension of Python. You should be able to use it as the following: import cv2

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install opencv-python==2.4.7
```

For python3 try:

```
pip3 install opencv-python==2.4.7
```

However, before you install opencv, have numpy and matplotlib installed.

```
pip install numpy

pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Thanks, I installed numpy and matplotlib. I tried "pip install opencv-python==2.4.7", but I got the error message:  "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==2.4.7 (from versions: 3.1.0.0, 3.1.0.1, 3.1.0.2, 3.1.0.3, 3.1.0.4, 3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7, 3.2.0.8, 3.3.0.9, 3.3.0.10, 3.3.1.11, 3.4.0.12, 3.4.0.14, 3.4.1.15, 3.4.2.16, 3.4.2.17, 3.4.3.18)
No matching distribution found for opencv-python==2.4.7"

Comment: It seems OpenCV 2.4 version is no longer supported on the distribution repo.

Comment: @HowardGENG my bad. Should I delete my answer? As it is no longer applicable.

Comment: It is up to you. You answer works well for other versions.